# Event on sheet activate

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-api

I want to update my sidebar whenever user clicks on different sheets. Basically, whenever a sheet is activated. I have explored onChange and onEdit events but they don't help my cause. I didn't come across any apps-script event which will help me capture sheet activations. Is there any way we can capture
onSheetActivate?

Comment: Get your sidebar code to poll.

Comment: Actually, updating sidebar is just one of the tasks that I want to do. The main area of concern is capturing the sheet activate event. If there is a sidebar, I can poll it. But, what about use cases where I don't have a sidebar. Say, I want to update the menu items on sheet activate. I have a dynamic menu which gets updated based on the contents of a sheet. when I am on sheet1, I have menu1 and on sheet2, I have to show menu2. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: There is no such event

Comment: Any other way of getting this done?